# Scarlet Solo 2nd + AT2020 noise problem appears after some time

Tags: microphone, dac

So I bought the audio equipment mentioned in the title recently and I have been having some problems with it.
After some time, randomly (Today it happened two times for example) mic starts going static/my voice becomes robotic. With no clear reproduction steps.

What fixes the problem is pulling out scarlet's usb from pc (haven't tried pulling from scarlet itself, I suppose the effect would be the same) and plugging it back in.

Could having all usb slots on my PC occupied have an affect?
CPU: Intel Core i7-2600k @ 3.4GHz
MB: Asus P8Z68-V PRO

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a product support question that should be directed at the manufacturers concerned.

Comment: I think this might be a more general troubleshooting problem related to buffering.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a buffer problem to me.  Try increasing the buffer in the software and see if it fixes the problem.  Both items you bought are very decent so I doubt it's a hardware problem, especially with the symptoms you describe.

Answer (score 0):

My first suspect would be other software that is running on the computer while you are trying to record.  Remember that MS Windows is NOT a "real-time" operating system. When recording on a PC, you must not take for granted that the CPU will ALWAYS have the on-demand, real-time "horsepower" to continuously record without interruption.

I would carefully comb through all the other things that are running and stop/unload any unnecessary layered apps. And even then, there are still scores (perhaps hundreds!) of little processes running in the background.

The fact that it starts out OK, and then goes bad sometime later at a random interval strongly suggests interference/conflict with other software processes.

Comment: While true that the windows OS isn't real-time, isn't this mitigated by hardware buffering by the audio interface?

Comment: Some tips for the issues mentioned in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/6206709/4023800